# Can Multiple Devices use the same VPN Tunnel IP?

Tags: vpn, firewall, tunnel

I have a Cybera Firewall device that has a VPN Tunnel IP that Verifone uses to connect to the firewall to configure the Verifone Commander for Help Desk reasons. Can I use that same tunnel IP to have another server connect to the firewall and establish a connection to a PC that is connected to the Cybera device?

Comment: It depends on the particular VPN, but most likely. You may have to quit one device to start another.  Numerous issues: VPN type, security.

Comment: @John - Unfortunately I do not know what type of VPN that the Cybera firewall uses. I may need to install OpenVPN or another VPN software on the PC to establish the connection instead of relying on the existing tunnel.

Comment: Looks like it's just a basic OpenVPN server, so yes it's possible, and yes you will need VPN software on the external PC. It depends on the firewall configuration though - "Tunnel" often refers to a site-to-site vpn rather than a client-server for example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - The issue has been resolved, I ended up using OpenVPN to establish a client-to-server connection.